# Is getopts always available for Bash?

Tags: bash, portability

Can I use `getopts` for parsing command-line arguments in my `bash` scripts(not `sh`) without worrying about another depedency?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$ type getopts
getopts is a shell builtin
```

`getopts` is built in, so it's present anywhere bash is.

To be sure of that you'd need to check the bash documentation to see whether it's an optional feature — it isn't.

More precisely, this tells you that `getopts` is available in this particular version of bash. You need to check the release notes for older versions to see when `getopts` was introduced; that happened before the dawn of time (it was already present in bash 1.14 and you'd have a hard time finding a version that old).

Even better, you can count on `getopts` even in shells that aren't bash, since it's [required by POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xcu/getopts.html).

Comment: Note that `getopt` is not the same as `getopts`. `getopt` is a standalone program.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, check `man getopts`. Even though `getopts` is a program in `/usr/bin` You can see that it redirects you to a list of builtin bash commands `BASH_BUILTINS(1)` and that the bash documentation specifically refers to `getopts`.

```
    getopts optstring name [args]
        ...
```

For more detailed usage of how to use getopts see ["example of how to use getopts in bash"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16483119/example-of-how-to-use-getopts-in-bash)

Comment: Woud you mind detailing more the answer, man page quotation, how to use? There is nothing against you answering you own posts, however I would advise you  to write answers of better quality.